# Zend DB Union not working

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I was given the task of translating an old query into Zend and all was going well until I went to create the union. I cannot post the actual contents of the query due to company regulations but basically what I have is:

```
$sql1 = $db->select()
    ->from(array('t' => 'tableOne'), array('t.id'))
    ->joinLeft(array('tt' => 'tableTwo'), 'tt.fk_tableOne_id = t.id', array())
    ->where($db->quoteInto('tt.active = ?', 'Y'));
$sql2 = $db->select()
    ->from(array('t' => 'tableOne'), array('t.id'))
    ->joinLeft(array('tt' => 'tableTwo'), 'tt.fk_tableOne_id = t.id', array())
    ->where($db->quoteInto('tt.active = ?', 'Y'));
$select = $db->select()->union(array($sql1, $sql2))->order('t.id');
```

Now, if I do a fetchAll on $sql1, it works. If I do a fetchAll on $sql2, it works. However, when I do a fetchAll on $select I get an error 1064 Syntax Error.

The sql string echoed by `echo $select` is basically

```
(ORDER BY `t.id` ASC) UNION (SELECT ... ) UNION (SELECT ...)
```

With the syntax error near ORDER BY ...

It seems like this should all be working since the two queries work independently, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a slightly modified query from yours:

```
$sql1 = $zdb->select()
    ->from(array('t' => 'articles'), array('t.id'))
    ->joinLeft(array('tt' => 'users'), 'tt.id = t.author_id', array())
    ->where($zdb->quoteInto('tt.level = ?', 'editor'));
$sql2 = $zdb->select()
    ->from(array('t' => 'blogs'), array('t.id'))
    ->joinLeft(array('tt' => 'users'), 'tt.id = t.updated_by', array())
    ->where($zdb->quoteInto('tt.level = ?', 'editor'));
$select = $zdb->select()->union(array($sql1, $sql2))->order('id');

echo $select;
```

and got the following:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` FROM `articles` AS `t` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tt` ON tt.id = t.author_id
WHERE (tt.level = 'editor') UNION SELECT `t`.`id` FROM `blogs` AS `t` LEFT JOIN `users`
AS `tt` ON tt.id = t.updated_by WHERE (tt.level = 'editor') ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

What version of the framework do you have?

Comment: I am not sure what version we are using, what I ended up doing to get it to work was $union = $db->select()->distinct()->calcRows()->from($sql1->union(array($sql2)))->order($sort)->limitPage($page, $limit); And that worked. Probably is an issue with an older framework, the Config.php file lists copyright as 2005-2008, so I am assuming our framework is older

Comment: FYI, find the Version.php within your ZF install; the constant `VERSION` will tell you.